# MinGW compiler : unable to run program in command prompt

Tags: c, mingw

I downloaded MinGW compiler . I wrote a small c program and compiled it as follow :

```
gcc -c firstc.c
```

It generated an executable file as "firstc.o" .

But when I tried to run the program in command prompt as follow  :

```
firstc.o
```

It resulted in a prompt window stating

" How do you want to open this file ?"

and with a list of options of apps to opt for .

What might be the issue here ? How can I redirect the output of my program in command prompt itself ?

If in case the program can be suspected the following is the program in the file :

```
#include <stdio.h>

 struct gl
{ 

   int n ;
    char a[10];

} ;

 int 
main () {

     struct  gl* str_p ; 
    printf(" Meri marzi  /n") ;
     return 0 ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I compile and link a c program using gcc?

> It generated an executable file as "firstc.o"

`firstc.o` is an object module not an executable file. It needs to be linked (see later).

This is because you ran:

> ```
> gcc -c firstc.c
> ```

And `-c` instructs the compiler to:

> Compile or assemble the source files, but **do not link**. The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.

Source [Overall Options - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

To link in a separate step:

```
gcc -o firstc firstc.o -lm
```

To compile and link in one step:

```
gcc -Wall firstc.c -o firstc
```

To run your program:

```
./firstc
```

Finally, please read the following instructions on how to use gcc:

- [GCC and Make - A Tutorial on how to compile, link and build C/C++ applications](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)